# How to set header and footer using html2pdf - jspdf javascript plugin?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to convert HTML contents to a pdf file and store it to the server so, I used jspdf - html2pdf function for convert HTML contents to pdf file.

so i am trying a javascript code in angular project like that,

```
var element = this.pdfTable.nativeElement
var opt = {
  margin:       0.5,
  filename:     'ct-scan.pdf',
  enableLinks:  false,
  pagebreak:    { mode: 'avoid-all' },
  image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
  jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
};

 html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
 var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages(); 

 for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
   pdf.setPage(i);
   pdf.setFontSize(10);
   pdf.setTextColor(150);
   pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 100, 
   pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 30);
 } 
 }).save()
```

it works fine., but the header and footer are not set in the result. so anybody can help me to solve this issue? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since your unit is using inch `jsPDF: { unit: 'in' ...` , minus the width of 100 and the height of 30 will become negative number. The pdf won't show the text probably.

Solution: You can print the current width and height by `console.log`; or just divided by 2 to make it go center, then you can adjust the text to your desired position.

```
var element =  this.pdfTable.nativeElement;
var opt = {
  margin:       0.5,
  filename:     'ct-scan.pdf',
  enableLinks:  false,
  pagebreak:    { mode: 'avoid-all' },
  image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
  jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
};

 html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
 var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages(); 
 //print current pdf width & height to console
 console.log("getHeight:" + pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight());
 console.log("getWidth:" + pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth());
 for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
   pdf.setPage(i);
   pdf.setFontSize(10);
   pdf.setTextColor(150);
   //divided by 2 to go center
   pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth()/2, 
   pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight()/ 2);
 } 
 }).save();
```